# void setup/void drawでmissing operator,semicolon, or }　のエラー表示が消えない

Tags: processing

void setup/void drawでmissing operator,semicolon, or }　のエラー表示が消えなくて困っています。必要なものは書いてあるのうに思うのですがどこに何が必要なのでしょうか。教えていただけると幸いです。

```
size(800,800);
background(0);
stroke(219,18,128);

//orion
line(300,330,330,280);
line(310,320,310,320);
line(305,330,400,400);

noFill();
beginShape();
vertex(400,400);
vertex(460,450);
vertex(455,500);
vertex(500,490);
vertex(470,440);
vertex(480,395);
vertex(440,380);
endShape(CLOSE);

line(480,395,500,330);
line(500,330,530,390);
line(530,390,540,410);
//star
for (int y = 0; y<=height; y += 100){
  for (int x = 0; x <= width; x+=100){
    fill(219,18,128);
    ellipse(x,y,1,1);
  }
}

void setup(){
  strokeWeight(4);
  stroke(0,50);
}

void draw(){
  float weight = dist(mouseX,mouseY,pmouseX, pmouseY);
  strokeWeight(weight);
  line(mouseX,mouseY,pmouseX,pmouseY);
}
```

Comment: どのようなコマンドを実行するとどのような出力が出るのか、省略せずに書かれると良いかと思います。

Comment: @quasar  こちらが表示されるメッセージです。void setup, void drawingに下線がひかれています。　
"Missing operator, semicolon, or '}' near 'setup'?" でエラー